# How to set a variable to a piece of another variable

Tags: batch-file

Basically I was wondering if you can set a variable to half or a part of another variable.

```
set /a var1=3000

set var1a=30
set var1b=00
```

It can't be as simple as just setting it to the two parts, because the user will be able to increase it or decrease it as they wish. For example:

```
@echo off
set /a var1=800
:function
echo %var1%
echo [1] +120
echo [2] -55
choice /c 12 /n
if %errorlevel% == 1 (set /a var1=%var1%+120)
if %errorlevel% == 2 (set /a var1=%var1%-55)
goto function
```

So I have to be able to just set a variable to a segment of the variable.

Comment: Half or Part are distinctly two different concepts.  Regardless you can do substrings. `set "var1a=%var1:~0,2%"`. I have no idea what your first set of code has to do with your second set of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set a variable to the leading *n* characters of another variable using the following syntax:

```
SET VAR=VALUE
SET START=%VAR:~0,2%
SET END=%VAR:~2%
ECHO.%START%
ECHO.%END%
```

This will output the following

```
VA
LUE
```

If your goal is to make these variables dynamic so that they will still be the beginning and end of `VAR`, even if it changes later, this approach will not acheive that:

```
SET VAR=VALUE
SET START=%VAR:~0,2%
SET END=%VAR:~2%

SET VAR=NEWVALUE
ECHO.%VAR%
ECHO.%START% ^!= %VAR:~0,2%
ECHO.%END% ^!= %VAR:~2%
```

will produce:

```
NEWVALUE
VA != NE
LUE != WVALUE
```

However, `%VAR:~0,2%` will always contain the first two characters of `%VAR%` and `%VAR:~2%` will always contain the contents of `%VAR%` after the first two characters, so it may be possible to use these directly where you need them.

Comment: The statement: `If your goal is to make these variables dynamic so that they will still be the beginning and end of VAR, even if it changes later, this is not possible in Batch
` Is entirely incorrect. by defining start and end using `!` expansion prior to delayed expansion being enabled, then enabling delayed expansion, the current value will be available. I suggest reading [this topic](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1827)  regarding how this fact can be used to create variables that perform functions to understand how powerful this can be where batch scripting is concerned.

Comment: @T3RR0R I have removed the claim that it is not possible. Please feel free to add your own answer explaining how to do this.